# Pycharm no longer connects to vagrant machine after upgrading Vagrant and VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, pycharm

After upgrading Windows 10, I noticed that I couldn't set my vagrant machine up because VirtualBox 4.3 didn't start. So I upgraded it to 5.0 and consequently upgraded Vagrant to 1.8 from 1.7.

Then in Pycharm (both v4 and v5), the connection to my vagrant linux machine didn't work. I've been working with it for months. I tried to edit it and set it again but I receive a **Java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\devops\vagrant-trusty\.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\private_key" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)**

The file is in place. I didn't change anything.

### Workaround

If I create a ssh remote connection instead of a vagrant one, it works. That is, I manually set the host 127.0.0.1:2222, user "vagrant" and path to key "C:\devops\vagrant-trusty\.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\private_key" and it works.

So configuring the remote connection as vagrant doesn't find the path, but as ssh it does (?)

Does anybody know if this is a problem with vagrant, virtualbox, windows folder permissions,...?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with windows. I just had the same error on my Macbook. Tried to create a vagrant connection with both Pycharm 5.0.1 and 5.0.3 but both times is said "couldn't connect to vagrant"

Your work around worked for me

Comment: Workaround won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue. The path (private_key) had folders with spaces in it. I renamed the folders, deleted .idea directory, opened in pycharm and it worked.